# mypy does not detect errors when wrongly using a function imported from an external package

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I've run a simple experiment where I've created a very simple python package containing the following files:
In the folder `my_package`:

```py
# example.py
def foo(number: int, text: str) -> None:
    print(number)
    print(text)
```

An empty `__init__.py`

In the root folder, a `setup.py` file:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='ExamplePackage',
    version='0.1.0',
    author='An Awesome Coder',
    author_email='aac@example.com',
    packages=['my_package'],
    description='An awesome package that does something',
)
```

After building the package using `python ./setup.py bdist_wheel` I've copied the `.whl` file to another python project, ran `pip install ExamplePackage-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl` and created the following file `main.py`:

```py
from my_package.example import foo

# No mypy errors at all!
x = foo()

def internal_foo(number: int, text: str) -> None:
    print(number)
    print(text)


# Missing positional arguments "number", "text" in call to "internal_foo"  [call-arg]
# "internal_foo" does not return a value  [func-returns-value]
y = internal_foo()
```

My `mypy.ini` looks like this:

```ini
[mypy]
ignore_missing_imports = True
show_error_codes = True
strict = True
check_untyped_defs = True
raise_exceptions = True
```

I'm struggling to understand why mypy which could easily infer the signature of the imported `foo` function, does not show any errors regarding the wrong usage

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: That external package needs `py.typed` marker in package root, otherwise `mypy` does not look for annotations in the source, as per [PEP561](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/)

Comment: @SUTerliakov  Thank you so much! Please post your reply as an answer so I can mark it the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PEP-561](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/) (a python standard that regulates use of typing data for packages), there are two general ways to declare types for package.

The first (applicable in your case) is `py.typed` marker. It is an empty file named `py.typed`, placed in package root (the same place where the topmost `__init__.py` resides; for namespace packages prefer adding `py.typed` to every submodule to avoid inconsistent interpretation). It declares that the package contains inline type information.

It is important not to forget to **add it as package data**. You need to add it as `MANIFEST.in` entry + any configuration necessary to enable it - nothing for `pyproject.toml`-based packages, `include_package_data = True` for `setup.py` and `setup.cfg`, something else (similar?) for non-setuptools distros (Poetry, flit, hatch or whatever you need for some reason). Alternatively, it can be declared in `[tool.setuptools.package-data]` section of `pyproject.toml`, `package_data` in `setup.py`, `[options.package_data]` in `setup.cfg` and something similar for other build systems. There are other options like VCS integration (from `.gitignore` and similar files) with appropriate plugins, refer to setuptools documentation [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/datafiles.html) or docs for system of your choice.

Another supported solution is using stub files - these are separate files with `.pyi` extension, providing only typing for functions/methods and variables/attributes. They have a higher precedence (e.g. if there are both stubs and `py.typed`, stubs types are used), but this should not happen (if code can be annotated inline, then there is no need in separate stubs). Stub packages are named `<package>-stubs`. There are also "side-by-side" approach that allows putting `.py` and `.pyi` near each other.